# Duvida sobre normalização de polinómios

Tags: haskell

Defini a função normaliza que dado um polinómio, devolve o polinómio correspondente, após ser normalizado.

Exemplo:

```
normaliza [(1,2),(3,4),(3,2)]

[(4,1),(3,4)]

type Polinomio = [Monomio]

type Monomio = (Float,Int)

normaliza :: Polinomio -> Polinomio

normaliza [(x,y)] = [(x,y)]

normaliza ((x,y): t) = (map (+) coeficientes (selgrau y  (x,y):t)) ((x,y) : t)

coeficientes :: [(Float,Int)] -> [Float]

coeficientes [(x,y)] = [x]

coeficientes (h:t) = fst h : coeficientes t

selgrau :: Int -> Polinomio -> Polinomio  

selgrau n [] = []

selgrau n l = filter f l   

            where f (c,e) = e == n
```

Será que me podem ajudar :)

Comment: Mas qual é o seu problema, afinal? Onde você acha que está o erro?

Comment: Estava na definição da função normaliza... Já encontrei uma resolução alternativa